# After Build Bundle, There is no aab file in release folder

Tags: android, android-bundle

The only file in release is the build apk. The aab file is only in debug folder eventhough already  choose release when want to generate sign bundle.

Comment: This is the path where my project's **app.aab** files genereated --> Project_path/app/build/outputs/bundle/release.

Comment: @pradiptilala There is no release folder. Only debug folder.

Comment: Are you using Terminal(Command line) OR Android Studio to generate Bundle??  You can also go to your Project root folder and search for .aab files

Comment: using Android Studio.I already find it but only generated in debug folder.

Comment: My app-release.aab was in --> Project_path/app/release

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Already solved the problem. Just checked the build variant are debug so thats why it does not appear. Just choose release and it will generated the file.

Build - Select build variant -Release .

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that
I used the command following command but my aab was not being generated.

```
npx react-native build-android --mode=release
```

but when I changed to :-
cd android and

```
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

It worked fine!!
and also you have to generate keystore too by :
windows:

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

mac:

```
sudo keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was not setting the Key Alias correctly which resulted in no building at the end and therefore no aab, but wierdly no error at all. Anyway I set the Key Alias correctly and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

.aab the release file is in app/build/outputs/bundle/[build flavor]Release

And the debug version is in app/build/outputs/bundle/[build flavor]Debug

Answer (score 0):

Check Release folder under Release as it has gone one folder down.
[image: Signed Bundle for Release]

Comment: I only have 1 release folder only.