# GitHub Actions Error on r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1 -> no such file or directory, scandir 'app/build/outputs/bundle/release'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, github-actions, gradlew, android-bundle

I am getting this error:

> Run r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1 Preparing to sign key @
> app/build/outputs/bundle/release with signing key Error: ENOENT: no
> such file or directory, scandir 'app/build/outputs/bundle/release'

I see in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54341124/after-build-bundle-there-is-no-aab-file-in-release-folder#:%7E:text=.aab%20the%20release%20file%20is%20in%20app%2Fbuild%2Foutputs%2Fbundle%2F%20%5Bbuild,debug%20version%20is%20in%20app%2Fbuild%2Foutputs%2Fbundle%2F%20%5Bbuild%20flavor%5DDebug%20Share) that the app/build/outputs/bundle/[build flavor]release, but that's not where it is going on my machine, it goes to [app]/mobile/release. I expect there is a way to configure this, but am having trouble finding it.

I have also tried with `releaseDirectory: app/mobile/release` but got the same error.

It would be great to see the path/file during the **Build Release AAB** step so I could try to use it in the next step. When I run interactively through Android Studio, I can see the output is available:

[image]

I wish I could have it print to the build output.

Also I'm a little confused by the 'app' part of the path. On my local machine that obviously gets replaced by my app path, so how does using it in another action, like **Sign Android Release** know to use the right path? I guess it worked with the example posts ([this](https://www.valueof.io/blog/deploying-to-google-play-using-github-actions), [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/use-github-actions-to-automate-android-development/), and [this](https://medium.com/@niraj_prajapati/automate-android-app-publishing-on-play-store-using-github-actions-554de7801c36#:%7E:text=Automate%20Android%20App%20Publishing%20on%20Play%20Store%20using,Deploy%20to%20Play%20Store.%20...%20More%20items...%20)), but I don't know how.

In my case I'm generating two aab files, but the r0adkll action seems to support [that](https://github.com/r0adkll/sign-android-release#signedreleasefiles--env-signed_release_files).

When running a GitHub action based on this yaml file:

```
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - '*'

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3.0.1
    - name: set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3.1.1
      with:
        distribution: 'zulu'
        java-version: '8'
        
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
      
    - name: Build with Gradle
      id: build
      run: ./gradlew build
      
    - name: Build Release AAB
      id: buildRelease
      run: ./gradlew bundleRelease
      
    - name: Sign Android release
      uses: r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
      with:
        releaseDirectory: app/build/outputs/bundle/release
        signingKeyBase64: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY }}
        alias: ${{ secrets.ALIAS }}
        keyStorePassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD }}
        keyPassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}
```

I've been following these examples:

- [How to Use GitHub Actions to Automate Android App Development](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/use-github-actions-to-automate-android-development/)
- [Automate Android App Publishing on Play Store using GitHub Actions](https://medium.com/@niraj_prajapati/automate-android-app-publishing-on-play-store-using-github-actions-554de7801c36#:%7E:text=Automate%20Android%20App%20Publishing%20on%20Play%20Store%20using,Deploy%20to%20Play%20Store.%20...%20More%20items...%20)
- [Deploying to Google Play Store using Github Actions](https://www.valueof.io/blog/deploying-to-google-play-using-github-actions)

But had to change the setup jdk, due to the environment files github change.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/home/runner/work/<repo name>/<repo name>/android/app/release`